# strcat incompatible types error in C

Tags: c, string, strcat, incompatibletypeerror

I have a 2d character array of the form `arr[][]`. I need to add a single character to the end and sometimes to the beginning of the ith or jth row in this array. Here is the code snippet:

```
 arr[j] = strcat(arr[j],")");
 arr[i] = strcat("(",arr[i]);
```

When I compile the code, I get the error: incompatible types in assignment. Now I am assuming `arr[j]` and `arr[i]` are strings. Where am I going wrong? In other words, what is the best practice to append or add a character to the beginning of a string?

Comment: you must take care of the fact that `char *arr[]` (case 1) and `char arr[][]` (case 2) are two different things in C. In the first case here (& for your first case), the concatenation will happen at the end of `arr[final_position][final_position]`, but in the second case here, it will happen at `arr[j][final_position]`. Here, in case 1, it is an array of pointers and in the case 2, it is a 2-D array. So, in case 2, the strings-continuity will end at (`'\0'` occurrence) the final-end since the memory allocated is in continuum for all the strings in the 2-D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you cannot assign the `char *` returned by `strcat` to an existing array row.

But more importantly, `strcat` does not allocate a new string with the result of the concatenation, but instead performs the concatenation inplace in the first string. The return value is always the first string and is just a convenience. So, in the first case you just have to do:

```
strcat(arr[j],")");
```

(assuming `arr[j]` is big enough for the added character)

The second case is more complicated, since you have to add the `)` to the beginning of an existing string. You can e.g. perform the operation in a separated buffer and then copy it back to `arr[j]` using `strcpy`, or move the whole content of the string one character forward and add the parenthesis manually:

```
memmove(arr[j]+1, arr[j], strlen(arr[j]));
arr[j][0]='(';
```

---

From your mistake I fear you think that `char *` is like the string classes in other languages, but alas it's not like that. Remember, in C strings are just dumb arrays of characters, don't expect any fancy commodities as in higher-level languages.

Comment: Thanx for clarifying me doubt Matteo. Pardon me if I am being greedy, but is there a shorter way of adding a character to the beginning of the string? :P I mean from what I can guess it is of the efficiency of O(n) if we either shift every character by 1 place or copy all of the characters to a separate string.

Comment: Shorter in code or with better efficiency? Anyhow, I don't think you can get shorter than two lines (but you could encapsulate that [in a function](http://pastebin.com/8sCismpA) that handles the general case), and, due to the fact that strings are vectors, you cannot beat O(N) for insertion at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Pl. see if the simple example below helps,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char myarray[2][10], *temp;

    //Populating something in the array
    strcpy(myarray[0], "string1");
    strcpy(myarray[1], "string2");
    printf("%s\n", myarray[0]);
    printf("%s\n", myarray[1]);

    //Adding something at the end of the string..
    //Be careful to check if the source is large enough.
    //Also consider using strncat
    strcat(myarray[0], ")");
    printf("Appended at the end %s\n", myarray[0]);

    //Append at the beginning
    //Here you can use a temporary storage.
    //And pl. do the required error handling for insufficent space.
    temp = malloc(strlen(myarray[1]) + strlen("(") +1);
    strcat(temp, "(");
    strcat(temp, myarray[1]);
    strcpy(myarray[1], temp);
    printf("Appended at the beginning  %s\n", myarray[1]);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot `free(temp)`; also, keep in mind that allocating with `malloc` is going to be way slower than shifting the string in-place.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, Thanks Matteo. I have added the `free(temp)`